Spring Cloud Gateway as router with "predicates"
I need a HTTP gateway router, that would check from post requst json body, if there is a string value of given pattern. And use that value to determine where to forward each request.
Like
productID contains "AA"

docs.spring.io does not give an example for this kind of "predicating".
Otherwise Spring Cloud Gateway seems to be just the great tool for our "gateway router" needs. Just configure. No code ;)

Or some other way of just forward a http request to target A or target B. By checking a value from request post json body.

Next day, after studing Spring Cloud Gateway:
org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.PredicateSpec  :

/**
 * This predicate is BETA and may be subject to change in a future release. A
 * predicate that checks the contents of the request body
 * @param inClass the class to parse the body to
 * @param predicate a predicate to check the contents of the body
 * @param <T> the type the body is parsed to
 * @return a {@link BooleanSpec} to be used to add logical operators
 */
public <T> BooleanSpec readBody(Class<T> inClass, Predicate<T> predicate) {
    return asyncPredicate(
            getBean(ReadBodyRoutePredicateFactory.class).applyAsync(c -> c.setPredicate(inClass, predicate)));
}


If someone has coded and used or seen an example usage / test of that "readBody() method, please share here !
